# Which architectures and OSes should I target when distributing on PyPI?

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

I have a Python module I've been working on. Perhaps unfortunately, it requires some compiled C code to be bundled with it. I've got it building in Linux and OSX with Travis and Windows with Appveyor.

I was wondering if there's a recommended set of architectures, OSes and Python API versions I should target. My gut feeling is that I should try to be comprehensive and do x86 and x86_64 for each of Python 2.6, 2.7 and all of 3.0 - 3.6. This is likely already quite a few distributions, but are there others I'm not thinking of? ARM?

And more broadly, is there a set of Travis and Appveyor files that sets up an appropriate matrix to manage this build and distribution?

Comment: See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cibuildwheel and https://github.com/matthew-brett/multibuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.6 has been EOLed long time ago, though some poor ancient RHEL might be stuck with it. 3.0 and 3.1 was used in production by no one at all; 3.2, 3.3 are only on older Unix servers that I doubt see much new software development. In any case, I'd target 2.7 + 3.4+ and those that could be offered with comparative ease; anyone else wouldn't mind compiling the extension, because they'd be waist-deep in ... anyhow.

As for the Travis / Appveyor thing, this sounds dangerously like a resource request, which are off-topic to Stack Overflow.

However, I can give the hint that [Python Packaging Authority](https://github.com/pypa) provides [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux) Linux images for Docker; these are based on Centos 5, and have CPython 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6. They're used to build wheels with `manylinux1` tag. And there is an official [manylinux demo project](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo) too.

---

As for ARM - there are *way too many* variants there to support. For example Linux has quite a lot more more ABIs than on x86. For example there is the distinction of hard floating point vs soft floating point; 32 vs 64 bit... etc. Most of the ARM developers can very well compile the modules for their odd architecture themselves.